# How to setup textbox caret position to end of text?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have Window with Frame and Page inside that frame.

That Page has one TextBox and i want to navigate that frame to another Page when someone started writing to that TextBox(similiar to google searching, when search result appears immediately on different view when you starts writing).

I am now using same DataContext for both Page objects, so they can both read the value of property searchedText, which i have binded to TextBox on each Page.

**Page Search.xml:**

```
<Page x:Class="Customer_UI.Search"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
      Title="Search">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Name="searchBox" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="30" FontSize="28" Padding="10" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="5" KeyUp="TextBox_KeyUp" Text="{Binding Path=SearchedCustomer}" >
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**Search code-behind:**

```
namespace Customer_UI
{
    public partial class Search : Page
    {
        private void TextBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            SearchExpanded searchExpanded = new SearchExpanded();
            searchExpanded.DataContext = this.DataContext;
            (this.DataContext as MainWindow.MainWindowContext).MainWindow.MainFrame.Navigate(searchExpanded);
            searchExpanded.FocusSearchBox();
        }
    }
}
```

**Page SearchExpanded.xml:**

```
<Page x:Class="Customer_UI.SearchExpanded"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
      Title="SearchExpanded">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Name="searchBox" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="18" Padding="10" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="5" Text="{Binding Path=SearchedCustomer}" >
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**SearchExpanded code behind:**

```
namespace Customer_UI
{
    public partial class SearchExpanded : Page
    {
        public void FocusSearchBox() 
        {   
            MainWindow.MainWindowContext dc = DataContext as MainWindow.MainWindowContext;
            // this has no output, the input from TextBox on Page that causes navigation to this page is probably still not reflected to dataContext.searchedCustomer property
            Console.WriteLine(dc.SearchedCustomer);

            // problem is that this time dc.SearchedCustomer has still lenght zero

            searchBox.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the SelectionStart property to the length of the text.

Comment: but where? Read please that comment in FocusSearchBox method in SearchExpanded. The searchedCustomer property has length 0 when the method is executed.